# Java8 : LocalDateTime or TimeStamp

Tags: java, java-8

Which is more preferable at when or where ?

I don't know exactly what are actual differences between them.

From documentation of [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

> ...Time is represented to nanosecond precision. For example, the value "2nd October 2007 at 13:45.30.123456789" can
>   be stored in a LocalDateTime.

I assumed LocalDateTime can also accept until nanoseconds.So I think , I can replace my codes with [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) these are declared as [TimeStamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Scenario : we had planned to upgrade our project with Java-8. Modified old codes styles with new features of JAVA-8 (eg:Lambda,Streams etc;). But we got trouble while deciding for Dates and Times. Most of codes with `java.util.Date` were changed to `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.LocalDateTime`. For the cases of [TimeStamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) , I have no idea about the question

Should we replace them with [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) ?

Comment: Please only format text as a quote when it is an actual quote

Comment: `TimeStamp` is an SQL type. If you are not working with a database, there is no reason to use anything in the `java.sql` package.

Comment: @RealSkeptic for the cases, I am not working with database but I'd like to use with nano seconds or I am working with database but framework supports to use with java-8 dataTime api (eg:mybatis), which should I choose ?

Comment: nanoseconds IMHO are rarely connected with "human" time

Comment: @JacekCz For instance , I save uploaded files with actual file name + timestamp.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In current development you should prefer `LocalDateTime` and the other Java8 time classes.

- They provide the advantage of a much clearer separation between point-in-time definitions (`Instant`) and duration (`Duration`) or fragment based definitions (`LocalDate`, `LocalTime`).
- They allow a really good set of methods for manipulation/calculation logic (in difference to `java.util.Date`).
- Also unit conversion is covered (`Duration.toDays()`).
- Last but not least the Timezone hell is covered (`ZonedDateTime`).

A little disadvantage is the lack of support by quite a lot third-party API you may want to take advantage of. But this should just be a matter of time and conversion from Java8 time API to Calendar/Date is no showstopper.

If you have a mature software then replacing the old Date/Calendar based interfaces by Java8 based ones is just a risk until you make use of some advantages mentioned above.

If you want to replace an old `TimeStamp` parameter with something out of the Java8 time toolbox then you may either use `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`. The difference is that `Instant` value is handled as `ZoneOffset.UTC` based, when it comes to calculation, while `LocalDateTime` is by definition without any timezone relation.

*Hint:* Using a `LocalDateTime` is a quite nice thing if something should happen at `2018-01-02 10:24:12` for the system in e.g. India and the system in the US. In nearly all other cases you may prefer explicitly defining a timezone using `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Both `java.util.Date` and and `java.sql.Timestamp` are actually equivalents of `java.time.Instant`, not `LocalDateTime`, Date Timestamp and Instant are instances of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), while LocalDateTime is a DateTime in *current time zone*.

You can clearly see that because both classes feature this nice method (inherited from `java.util.Date`):

```
java.util.Date::toInstant
```

What I assume you meant by replacing `Date` with `LocalDate` is you was actually replacing `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date`. Now, sql.Date IS an equivalent of LocalDate, and is not equivalent to Instant, because sql.Date lacks Time component (despite sql.Date being subclass of util.Date, calling `getSeconds()` on it will result in exception).

Comment: As my question *..Most of codes with `java.util.Date` were changed to `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.LocalDateTime`*.

Comment: I don't think that is right to represent `java.util.Date` with `java.time.LocalDate`, because such conversion requires knowledge of local time zone as well, which `java.util.Date` lacks. Of course, if you absolutely sure that this particular `Date` represents `LocalDate`, then by all means. However, I do not know what you know about your system, and to me, the most failthful conversion between them and `java.time` is `Date->Instant`.

Comment: Prior to `java.time`, there was no standard way to represent zone-indifferent dates and times in Java, so people naturally used the `java.util.Date` class and just used it in contexts where it didn't matter whether it was an "instance" or a "local date". So it makes sense to replace it with `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` in such cases. And `LocalDate` is *not* associated with a particular time zone. For that you have `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes, precisely. If you know that in context of a system that instance of `java.util.Date` is always a `LocalDate` and nothing else, then it's reasonable to convert, but only in this case. In fact, even instance of Timestamp can mean "LocalDate" in certain contexts. I still would say that `Timestamp` is an `Instant` though, and not `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate`, because I lack the knowledge of use-case and contexts.

Comment: I don't have too much exp or detail knowledges of each `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`,`java.sql.TimeStamp`,`java.time.LocalDate`,`java.time.LocalDateTime`. I just want to say *hey guys ... now our project was migrated to Java-8 and we used all of it's features as we can.*

Comment: @Cataclysm, ah. Well, migration to newer APIs can be justified because they offer quite nice toolset out of the box (remember those huge CalendarUtils, anyone?). But such migration will be a no-brainer only if there's a clear distinction in role of each field you will be refactoring.